# Swift UIButton Title Text: Rotation is causing issues with text sizing

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, rotation, resize

I am working on an MTG life counter app and am having issues with UIButtons and their title text not sizing properly after rotating for a vertical view. The text either comes out very small when I set the font size to adjust to fit width, or as "..." when I don't set the font size to adjust to fit the width.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WBoY.jpg

I have tried to set the font to adjust to fit width, but then it comes out very small and unreadable. If I don't set the font to adjust to fit width, then the text comes out as "..."

```
// player 3 cell

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VerticalPlayerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VerticalPlayerTableViewCell
cell.player.name = playerData[2].name
cell.player.health = playerData[2].health
cell.playerTopButton.backgroundColor = playerData[2].playerColor
cell.playerTopButton.setTitle(String(cell.player.health), for: .normal)
cell.playerBottomButton.backgroundColor = playerData[2].playerColor
cell.playerBottomButton.setTitle(cell.player.name, for: .normal)

// rotating top button title text
cell.playerTopButton.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat.pi / 2) )
cell.playerTopButton.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
cell.playerTopButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1

// rotating bottom button title text
cell.playerBottomButton.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat.pi / 2))
cell.playerBottomButton.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
cell.playerBottomButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1

return cell
```

I was expecting the text to be fine after just rotating the `UIButton` title label 90 degrees to the right.

Comment: Did you try `sizeToFit`?

Comment: I have and that does about the same as adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth